# Flex 4.5 / Apache Flex UI Framework Architecture

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Is there any framework for UI development in Flex 4.5 ? Better standard for creating UI view layers using Action script. Also how to create states and state transitions in Action script?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any framework for UI development in Flex 4.5 ?

Flex is a framework for UI Development.  You can read up on the [Flex Component Lifecycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html) for more information on how it works.

> Better standard for creating UI view layers using Action script.

I don't understand what you're asking for here.  You want a better standard than what?

> Also how to create states and state transitions in Action script?

You can create states and state transitions in ActionScript similar to how you do it in [MXML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ff1.html).  Every component has a [states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#states) array; and each entry in the state array will be an instance of the [State class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/State.html) which will have a bunch of 'commands' to add or remove children or change properties.  The full list is in the state class API documentation under the related API elements header.

Setting up states in ActionScript is tedious, though.

Comment: is there any particular way for creating good performance application through AS ? any examples ?

Comment: Great response given the question, I was a bit dumb-founded on how to respond (is there a good UI framework for this UI framework... think I almost had a recursive stroke, no offense Gowtham).

Comment: @Gowtham Yes; I've dealt with hundreds of Flash based applications in the past 10 years with great performance.  You'll have to more specific as to your problem is with performance.

Comment: Gowtham, very efficient AS3 can be written without any major issues there are tons of articles that pick apart different aspects of performance within the run-time.  Flex itself is in my opinion still a bit too heavy weight in terms of processing time for current mobile devices, that said there is no way to answer these questions they are too broad.  This isn't because of AS3 (insert any language into your question and it is not answerable).  Recently on my own mobile projects I've used Actuate for animation as it seems to perform well, there are lots of things to explore though.

Comment: @shaunhusain For mobile Flex Applications; I've only seen problems with list scrolling and view transitions.  The rest of the framework is "acceptable enough".  And thanks; I Wasn't sure how to respond either but my comment got so long I made it a formal answer.

Comment: Yeah I'll agree for the most part it is as you say "acceptable enough."  But compared against a native application you still get some lagging points that are very difficult to get around (I'm not sure but my guess is all the layout invalidation and sizing of components is a lot of processing).  Building what you get out of the box in Flex yourself, is also no easy task (or building everything 4 times for different platforms to get native performance).

Comment: @shaunhusain No argument; Native apps will be better.  That isn't unique to mobile devices. ;) For my Mobile game, the game board is very efficient [built AS3 only].  But the menus are all Flex, and they are less performant.

Comment: @shaunhusain some time i feel its bit difficult to perform effects for complex UI created in AS. But HTML developers performing good effects through css itself. Is that flex difficult framework or not having enough examples to do it simple and straight forward. I'm adding patches for effects and layouts to make it smooth and feel better...

Comment: @www.Flextras.com that actually my mistake , i forget the word "design patter" Is there any design patter for UI development in Flex 4.5 ?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of design patterns that can be used in UI Development with the Flex framework.  Design patterns are not usually language specific. But some design patterns that people have used are: Singletons, MVC, and Dependency Injection.